# What is acceptable Proof of Travel to get Passport inside 2 weeks?

Tags: usa, passports, canada, short-notice, proof-of-onward-travel

I'm planning a trip to Ontario, Canada from Alabama in the US and intend to drive across the border and stay with a family. I absolutely need to leave on the 20th of this month. The passport agency closest to me is in Atlanta. I have a appointment scheduled on the 7th of this month.

I'm required to provide proof of travel, but I'm not flying OR staying in a hotel OR going on company business. Is it still possible to get a passport expedited, and will a letter from the family I'm staying with help?

Any insight to how I can effectively get a passport quickly under these circumstances is appreciated.

Edit: I just found out about Passport Cards. Is this quicker/easier to get than a full blown passport book since I won't be flying internationally?

Comment: Expedited service? My fiance got her pp in under 2 weeks. She had mentioned on her form that she would be travelling to France with it.

Comment: Do you mean Ontario, California or Ontario, Canada?

Answer (score 3):

For some reason, proof of travel is not required if you apply at the Arkansas Passport Agency, according to [Where to Apply](http://travel.state.gov/content/passports/english/passports/information/where-to-apply.html).

If you've already got an appointment in Atlanta, then perhaps you should call the National Passport Information Center at 1-877-487-2778 and ask them what would be sufficient proof.